# Fragment injection without a dedicated subcomponent

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to use android-dagger to inject a fragment from a manually defined subcomponent:

```
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    AppModule::class,
    BuilderModule::class
])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<App>()

    fun someComponent(): SomeComponent

}
```

---

```
@Subcomponent
interface SomeComponent {

    fun inject(fragment: SomeFragment)

}
```

---

Execution fails with:

> IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class "SomeFragment"

---

However, if I create a fragment bind annotated with `@ContributesAndroidInjector` it executes fine. The doc states that all this does is create a subcomponent. Why can't I do that manually?

---

Minimal working project can be found on github:
https://github.com/absimas/fragment-injection

Comment: did you find solution? I can resolve injections for factory. It's HELL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ContributesAndroidInjector` creates a subcomponent, yes. [The docs](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.12/dagger/android/ContributesAndroidInjector.html) don't say anything more, but they don't assert that this *only* creates a subcomponent; it also installs it into the `Map<Class, AndroidInjector.Factory>` [multibinding](https://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings.html) that powers each of dagger.android's injection types.

You can see an example of this map binding on the [Android page of the Dagger User's Guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/android#injecting-fragment-objects):

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@FragmentKey(YourFragment.class)
abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Fragment>
    bindYourFragmentInjectorFactory(YourFragmentSubcomponent.Builder builder);
```

Note that this expects you to bind a Builder, not a Component: dagger.android expects that you'll want access to your Fragment instance from within your subcomponent, so the binding is for [`AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Fragment>`](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/android/AndroidInjector.Factory.html) such that [DispatchingAndroidInjector can call `create(Fragment)` on it](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/DispatchingAndroidInjector.java#L77-L79). This is designed to be compatible with `Subcomponent.Builder`, but it does require that you define your `@Subcomponent.Builder` nested interface that extends the adapter `AndroidInjector.Builder`. Pardon my Java on a Kotlin question:

```
/** No need for an explicit inject, because you must extend AndroidInjector. */
@Subcomponent
interface SomeComponent extends AndroidInjector<SomeFragment> {

  /**
   * This abstract class handles the final create(Fragment) method,
   * plus @BindsInstance.
   */
  @Subcomponent.Builder
  abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<SomeFragment> {}
}
```

---

**EDIT:** It occurs to me now that your title states you don't want a dedicated subcomponent; beyond using a manual definition instead of `@ContributesAndroidInjector`, if you want a *multi-Fragment subcomponent*, then you might run into some trouble with this advice: dagger.android requires implementations of `AndroidInjector<YourFragment>`, and because of erasure, you own't be able to have a single class implement multiple `AndroidInjector<T>` or `AndroidInjector.Builder<T>` interfaces or abstract classes. In those cases you might need to write a *manual AndroidInjector.Factory implementation* which calls the correct concrete `inject` method. However, this seems like a lot of work for the sake of creating a monolithic Fragment component, when best-practices dictate dagger.android's default: a small and specific component for each Fragment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Answered my question though not in the way I hoped.